# Asp.net webforms autosave

Tags: asp.net

I understand this may be an elementary question, but I'm new to Asp.net webforms, so please bear with me.

I have a lengthy form on a page that I would like to autosave when users type in a field, or make a selection. The problem is, all I've been able to find online is autosaves that work on a timer.  I'd prefer that it saves as the user makes their edits.  Also I would like just the individual form element being edited to be sent to the server to avoid sending the entire page back each time.

I've read that I should use a webservice to accomplish this, but since I want to autosave individual items and not the whole form on a timer, how would I set up a webservice to accomplish this?  I'm new to webservices I'd like to know what to read up on.  Any links are appreciated.

Also, how is the autosave functionality effected when using asp.net validation controls? I've looked around but can't tell if the entire page needs to be valid to make a trip to the server, or if just a single valid item can be sent itself.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set AutoPostBack=True on the field, and you add an OnChange event for it (this will vary depending on the type of field the user is interacting with), you can execute a save. Don't call Page.Validate in the methods where you're doing these updates. Call it when you hit the Submit button.

This could cause a LOT of round trips to the server, and it's a lot of code to write and debug.

The Timer approach is one call to one method on a repetitive basis. If you can I'd recommend going with a timer, but sometimes that's not an option.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thank you! I'll see if I can use a timer, since I don't want a lot of trips to the server.  It may be difficult with the forms I'm working with so using autopostback and the onchange event may be what I need.  Thanks again, I appreciate the help!

Comment: OK, if you do this at least set up your save function as a separate method and call it from all your OnChange events and submit button click. Also make sure your database will support partial records!

Comment: Great info to keep in mind before putting this in.  I'm still new to this so it's very helpful, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking this is what you'll want to setup on the client-side.  Ideally, you will end up with lots of tiny requests which do not require much power on the back-end.  This however depends on lots of variables including the database engine you're using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").blur(OnFieldChanged);
});

function OnFieldChanged()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    var isValid = ValidateField($this);
    if (isValid)
    {
        SaveField($this);
    }
}

function SaveField($field)
{
   if ($this.val() === $this.prop("oldVal")) return;

    var data = {
        id: $("idfield").val()
    };
    data[$field.attr("id")] = $field.val();

    $.post({..}).done(function() {
        NotifySaved($this);
        $this.prop("oldVal", $this.val());
    });
}

function ValidateField($field)
{
    // Validate the field with your method of choice, manually call Microsoft's client-side validate function or switch to jquery validate.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  I was looking into .blur and was thinking that may be an option too.  Very helpful to understand the process with the code, thank you!